# Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main

Tags: jruby, command-prompt

I have installed 1.7.2.jruby windows7 64 bit.When I tried to check jruby running from cmd.exe as jruby -v it shows error as :

**"Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main"**

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Define JRUBY_HOME class path to your windows environment variables and add jrubyinstalation/bin directory to the path

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Below is what I did to resolve it:

Step 1: Added JRUBY_HOME environment variable with installation directory as value(**without bin folder**). My path was C:\Tools\jruby-1.7.21. **See bin folder isn't included**.

Step 2: Added bin folder path to PATH environment variable, i.e. edit PATH and append C:\Tools\jruby-1.7.21\bin;